# How to merge two web projects?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web.xml

I have 2 different war project. And I would like merge this project to **one war**. Each is Spring project.
Spring project have java based configuration. Each project have similar controllers and bean.
I would like make sturcture like this:
localhost:9080/common/**project1**
localhost:9080/common/**project2**
How web.xml should be?

my web.xml:

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>bla.bla.web.WebConfig</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
   <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
   <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value></param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/project1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: You just need  deploy wars in one tomcat (or another web container). for tomcat: deploy project in webapps/project1 and webbapps/project2.

Comment: What is in your web.xml now? Generally web.xml only specifies the entry point for the SPring context. Also, since you are using Spring with Java config, consider getting rid of web.xml completely (if you are user servlet spec 3 and up)  http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html

Comment: @Leon I added my web.xml form one war to question. How add config for /project2/*

Answer (score 0):

As Cuzz stated, just simply deploy both wars in tomcat. Each of them will work independently since they have different servlet-mappings.

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/project1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and for second:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/project2/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But i would recommend you to move contents of both together. Then for instance if your servlet-mapping is:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/common/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In your controllers you will have:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/project1")
```

and for second:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/project2")
```

Comment: I think it will be trouble on sharing sessions.